# Conditionally change display image based on JSON results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm new to javascript and jQuery and I'm trying to display JSON results in the browser.  I'm attempting to create dynamic HTML, while inserting the JSON results.  Here is a sample of the JSON data:

```
[{"JobName":"JobDoSomething","JobStatus":2,"JobStatusString":"","JobPath":"\\Mart\\ControlCenter\\","JobType":1},
{"JobName":"JobDoSomething2","JobStatus":2,"JobStatusString":"","JobPath":"\\Mart\\ControlCenter\\","JobType":1},
{"JobName":"JobDoSomething3","JobStatus":4,"JobStatusString":"","JobPath":"\\Mart\\ControlCenter\\","JobType":0}
```

Here is the code that I'm using to display the results:

```
var seqIcon = 'img/BatchJobIcon.gif';
var jobIcon = 'img/Logo32x32.gif';
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                    divs[parseInt(divs.length) - 1].innerHTML += '<div id="' + result[i].JobName + '" class="outerDiv">' +
                        '<div class="middleDiv">' +
                            '<div class="innerDiv">' +
                                '<img  id="image" src=' + jobIcon + ' />' +
                                /* '<img id="image" src=' + 'if (' + result[i].JobType + '= 1) {' + "img/BatchJobIcon.gif" + '} else {' + jobIcon + '};' + '/>' + */
                                '<h3>' + result[i].JobName + '</h3>' +
                                    '<p class="JobPath">' + result[i].JobPath + ' ' + result[i].JobStatus + ' ' + result[i].JobType + '</p>' + 
                                    '<p> <input type="button" id="btnRunJob" class="btn-minimal" value="Run Job" />' +
                                    '<input type="button" id="btnGetLog" class="btn-minimal" value="Job Log" />' +
                                    '</p>' +
                              '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';

                    $('#jobContainer').append(divs)
                }
```

I would like to use something like line `<img id="image" src=' + 'if (' + result[i].JobType + '= 1) {' + "img/BatchJobIcon.gif" + '} else {' + jobIcon + '};' + '/>` (commented out above) to be able to swap the desired image based on the JobType from the JSON result, but this does not work.  Any insight or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just insert a logical statement that determines the correct img HTML output before you start appending everything? Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qmfax37j/)

Comment: No need to rewrite everything, just use ternary operators. I just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line must be:

```
'<img id="image" src=' + (result[i].JobType == 1 ? "img/BatchJobIcon.gif" : jobIcon) + '/>' +
```

Which translates to, if JobType variable equals 1 output "img/BatchJobIcon.gif", else output jobIcon variable.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding is the best way to do this. Frameworks like [Angular](http://angularjs.org), [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com) provide easier ways to do it, in them we only write the html once with special wildcards like `{{ result.JobName }}`  and apply repeat on the html using syntax like `repeat="result in results"`. You must read up on them if you find yourself having to do a lot of this.

With your approach, you could use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Check the code below, it is evaluated as:

```
+
if (row.JobType == 1) {
    "img/BatchJobIcon.gif"
} else {
    jobIcon
}
+
```

The code:

```
var seqIcon = 'img/BatchJobIcon.gif';
var jobIcon = 'img/Logo32x32.gif';
var html, $container = $('#jobContainer');
function formHtml(row) {
    return '<div id="' + row.JobName + '" class="outerDiv">' +
                    '<div class="middleDiv">' +
                        '<div class="innerDiv">' +
                            '<img  id="image" src=' + jobIcon + ' />' +
                            '<img id="image" src=' + (row.JobType == 1 ? "img/BatchJobIcon.gif" : jobIcon) + '/>' +
                            '<h3>' + row.JobName + '</h3>' +
                            '<p class="JobPath">' + row.JobPath + ' ' + row.JobStatus + ' ' + row.JobType + '</p>'                                    '<p> <input type="button" id="btnRunJob" class="btn-minimal" value="Run Job" />' +
                            '<input type="button" id="btnGetLog" class="btn-minimal" value="Job Log" />' +
                            '</p>' +
                      '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
           '</div>';
}
result.forEach(function (row, i) {
    html = formHtml(row);
    $container.append(html);
});
```